# what's the simplest and most effective way to get random records from a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get a list of users from my user collection, but need to get 20 from 10k+ randomly.  What's the cleanest and most effective way?

I was thinking of updating users with {random: Math.random()} every minute and then sorting by random....

Is there a cleaner / more effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your solution is pretty good : http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/

Comment: this is fine, but note the caveat mentioned in the page *"The random attribute cannot be considered to be uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 for that key. The net effect is that some documents from the result would appear much often than others"*

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of element and just change the offset

```
User.all.offset(rand(User.count).limit(20)
```

Comment: `offset` for large values is slow.